# NA/NaN argument in for loop

Tags: r

While runing the *for loop* I am getting below error. I am new to R and just started using it. Can any one help me to resolve the issue and also can guide me how to debug such issues, if occur in future

```
for(row_no in 1:nrow(sale_calander)){
  for(week in sale_calander[row_no,2] : sale_calander[row_no,3]){
    print(paste("The week is", week))
    weekly_order_adv_data[which(weekly_order_adv_data$week_no==week),"promotion_type"] <- sale_calander[row_no,4]
    }
}
```

**The Error which I am getting it is as given :**

> Error in sale_calander[row_no, 2]:sale_calander[row_no, 3] : 
>     NA/NaN argument

Comment: Hi, could you make a reproducible example by providing a sample of your data please?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sale_calander$column[row_no]` is a better way since it will yield a vector.
Or use:
`as.numeric(sale_calander[row_no,2]):as.numeric(sale_calander[row_no,3])` in the `for` loop